# Is there an quivalent to 'jump' or 'go to' in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, goto

I have this code:

```
values_nodelay = no_of_values(2:2:end)
no_of_values_x1 = (find(u~=[u(2:end), u(end)+1]));
no_of_values_x1 = no_of_values_x1(2:2:end)
l = 1;
delay = 2;
values_delay = [];
while l<=length(values_nodelay) 
    values_delay_temp = values_nodelay(l)-delay; 
    if delay>values_delay_temp

    end
    values_delay = [values_delay, values_delay_temp];
    l = l+1;
end
values_delay
```

I need a `goto` or `jump` function to the beginning of `while`, or an equivalent if anyone 
knows an easier way, that if `delay > values_delay_temp`, it won't become part of the final vector `values_delay`. Instead, I want to skip it and continue again with the `while` loop.

Comment: please don't just post code and expect people to analyse it. Explain what it does / is trying to do.

Comment: Read up on what `contine;` does as well as `break;` when applicable

Comment: I am very sorry if my post was unclear. I am new to this forum.

Comment: Kind Regards ! Answer beneath solved everything !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using jumps like `continue` or `break`, you could just do this:

```
if delay<=values_delay_temp
    values_delay=[values_delay, values_delay_temp];
end
```

In other words make the "default" behavior of the loop to do nothing, and then only increment your vector when you hit the right condition. It's much clearer and easier to debug.

Also instead of using vector concatenation like you have, I've found it's more efficient to do `values_delay(end+1) = values_delay_temp;` if you have to grow a vector in a loop.

Comment: counter must be placed after the 'end', now it is working, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` statement will stop the execution of a loop for the current iteration and continue with the next iteration, e.g.

```
while foo
    # stuff that will execute for all iterations
    if bar
        continue
    end
    # stuff that won't execute if bar is false
end
```

Although, in your specific case, why don't you just issue

`values_delay=[values_delay, values_delay_temp];`

and increase the loop counter when

`delay <= values_delay_temp`

is true?